# How to get inherited type of Form in ControlDesigner

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, designer

I am building a custom designer that will associate a control with a business property on the form. The form DealUI has properties Instrument and Product, which are a business items:

```
    Public Class DealUI
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form ' repetition of Inherits in Deal.Designed.vb, just to make the point

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    <Business(True)> _
    Public Property Product As String

    <Business(True)> _
    Public Property Instrument As String

End Class
```

The Business attribute is simply

```
NotInheritable Class BusinessAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Private _isBusiness As Boolean

    Sub New(isBusiness As Boolean)
        _isBusiness = isBusiness
    End Sub

End Class
```

The form contains a custom control, ProductTextBox of type PilotTextBox:

```
<DesignerAttribute(GetType(PilotControlDesigner)), _
ToolboxItem(GetType(PilotToolboxItem))> _
Public Class PilotTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Public Property Source As String

End Class
```

In the designer, when the selected control changes to ProductTextbox, I want to populate its Source property with the names of the Form's properties that have the BusinessAttribute (Instrument and Product), the user can then choose between Instrument and Product. The designer code is

```
Public Class PilotControlDesigner
    Inherits ControlDesigner

    Private Sub InitializeServices()
        Me.selectionService = GetService(GetType(ISelectionService))
        If (Me.selectionService IsNot Nothing) Then
            AddHandler Me.selectionService.SelectionChanged, AddressOf selectionService_SelectionChanged
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub selectionService_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If Me.selectionService IsNot Nothing Then
            If Me.selectionService.PrimarySelection Is Me.Control Then
                Dim form As Object = DesigningForm()
                If form IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each prop As PropertyInfo In form.GetType.GetProperties
                        Dim attr As Attribute = GetCustomAttribute(prop.ReflectedType, GetType(BusinessAttribute), False)
                        If attr IsNot Nothing Then
                            ' we've found a Business attribute
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function DesigningForm() As Object ' in fact, a form, or more precisely something that inherits from Form
        Dim host As IDesignerHost = CType(Me.Component.Site.GetService(GetType(IDesignerHost)), IDesignerHost)
        Dim container As IContainer = host.Container
        For Each comp As Component In container.Components
            If comp.GetType.IsAssignableFrom(GetType(Form)) Then ' or anything that inherits 'Form'
                return comp ' returns a Form, not a Deal!!
            End If
        Next comp
        Return nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

The selected control is a Deal (which inherits from Form), but the component in the designer is a Form, not a Deal (!! in the comment). I need to examine the Instrument and Product properties, which only exist on a Deal.

How can I obtain the **Deal** object in the designer?

Comment: Try Me.Control instead.

Comment: @hans thanks, but Me.Control also returns an object of type Form, not an object of type DealUI

Comment: @hans I wish I could: http://www.calvert.ch/download/invalidcast.png (I feel I'm making a fool of myself somewhere, but I can't see where >;-)

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to get at instance data in the designer. I have gotten something approaching what it seems like you want to work. (that is, link properties defined in the form to certain controls).   let me know if you are still working on this, and I will post a new answer.